# Fetching custom post type without knowing post type (REST API)

Tags: custom-post-types, rest-api

How can I fetch posts from a custom post type without actually including the post type in the query url?

The data I'm provided doesn't have a reference to the post type, so all I get is the post ID. I've tried querying without the post type and I just get

```
{"code":"rest_no_route","message":"No route was found matching the URL and request method.","data":{"status":404}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a generic REST API endpoint that just accepted a post ID. I've used the default `WP_REST_Posts_Controller` to handle some standard checks and format the response:

```php
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {

    register_rest_route( 'wpse/406874', 'post_data/(?P<id>\d+)', [
        'methods' => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
        'permission_callback' => '__return_true',
        'callback' => function ( WP_REST_Request $request ) {
            $id = (int) $request['id'];

            $post = get_post( $id );

            $post_type = get_post_type( $post );

            $valid_post_types = get_post_types([
                'public' => true,
                'show_in_rest' => true,
            ]);

            if ( ! in_array( $post_type, $valid_post_types ) ) {
                return new WP_Error( 'rest_post_invalid_id', __( 'Invalid post ID.' ), [ 'status' => 404 ] );
            }

            $controller = new WP_REST_Posts_Controller( $post_type );

            $check = $controller->get_item_permissions_check( $request );

            if ( $check !== true ) {
                return $check;
            }

            return $controller->get_item( $request );
        }
    ]);

});
```

This would mean any post of any public post type (& with `show_in_rest => true`) would be queryable via:

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wpse/406874/post_data/<id>
```

Comment: Thanks so much!